# PCL with Kinect (OpenNI Grabber)

Tags: kinect, point-cloud-library, openni, simple-openni

**Hi , I just want a point cloud from kinect device. I followed the below link to do so.
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/openni_grabber.php#openni-grabber

But I am getting the following error .
Please suggest me , what I am doing wrong ? :(

Your help is highly appreciable !!

```html
#include <pcl/console/parse.h>
#include <pcl\console\time.h>
#include <pcl\io\io.h>
#include <pcl\point_types.h>
#include<pcl\io\pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl\io\openni_grabber.h>
#include <pcl-1.7\pcl\io\openni_grabber.h>

#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>
#include "time.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <pcl\io\grabber.h>
#include<pcl\point_types.h>

#include <OpenNI.h>
#include<pcl\io\boost.h>

using namespace pcl;
using namespace std;

class SimpleOpenNIViewer
 {
   public:
     SimpleOpenNIViewer () : viewer ("PCL OpenNI Viewer") {}

     void cloud_cb_ (const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr &cloud)
     {
       if (!viewer.wasStopped())
         viewer.showCloud (cloud);
     }

     void run ()
     {
    // create a new grabber for OpenNI devices
       pcl::Grabber* interface = new pcl::OpenNIGrabber();
    
      // make callback function from member function
       boost::function<void (const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr&)> f =
         boost::bind (&SimpleOpenNIViewer::cloud_cb_, this, _1);

       interface->registerCallback (f);
      // start receiving point clouds
       interface->start ();

       while (!viewer.wasStopped())
       {
         boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::seconds (1));
       }

       interface->stop ();
     }

     pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer;
 };

 int main ()
 {
   SimpleOpenNIViewer v;
   v.run ();
   return 0;
 }
```

```html
1>------ Build started: Project: Experiment_PCL_Kinect, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Experiment_PCL.cpp
1>Experiment_PCL.cpp(92): error C2039: 'OpenNIGrabber' : is not a member of 'pcl'
1>Experiment_PCL.cpp(92): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'OpenNIGrabber'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Where did you get the PCL library? Make sure that OpenNI support is enabled.

Comment: I downloaded PCL 1.7.2 from the following link as I have Visual Studio 2012 installed in my PC. http://unanancyowen.com/?p=1255&lang=en

Comment: From the page you referenced: "This PCL All-in-one Installer does not include the OpenNI v1.x. For this reason, pcl::OpenNIGrabber is not available."

Comment: Can you please suggest me suitable link to download PCL compatible with Visual studio 2012 (win 32 PC).I have both OpenNI and OpenNI2 installed in my system.

Comment: AFAIR this installer included OpenNI2, so you may try using `OpenNI2Grabber` instead. If it's not available as well, then I'm afraid you'll need to compile from source. (Or you may also search/ask on pcl users mail list, maybe someone knows another installer with OpenNI support included.)

Comment: I placed openni2_grabber.h and openni2 folder in include/io folder of PCL 1.7.2 from the link https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl                         but getting the same error in my code!   :(