# Point cloud Library : Compatibility issue (Kinect//OpenNI/Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, kinect, point-cloud-library, openni

Getting point cloud from Kinect is the ultimate aim.

**Following availability :**

1. Visual Studio 2012 in Win 32 bit PC.
2. OpenNI2 and OpenNI.
3. Kinect X-Box 360

**Following  Issue:**
1. Tried PCL 1.7.2 All in One installer via the link :
unanancyowen.com/?p=1255&lang=en 
but it doesn't include OpenNI (in io folder of include)

2. error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'OpenNIGrabber'

**Please suggest me which version of PCL should I use and link to download .**

Thanks & Regards,
 Marie

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990116/pcl-with-kinect-openni-grabber) question is almost similar. That page from where you downloaded simply quotes that openni grabber is not provided. Instead, use the kinectgrabber provided by the same person